# How to export SwiftUI View with animation to animated GIF?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI View with some natively created animation. How can I export it to the animated GIF, or at least to the sequence of PNG images **without 3rd party libraries**? Transparency has to be preserved.

```
struct SimpleAnimationView: View {
    @State private var isFinalFrame = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let height = proxy.size.height
            let size = isFinalFrame ? height : height * 0.7
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.orange)
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                Color.clear
            }
        }
        .animation(
            .easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(),
            value: isFinalFrame
        )
        .task {
            if !isFinalFrame {
                isFinalFrame = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleAnimationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SimpleAnimationView()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to do this programmatically at runtime?

Comment: I'm afraid your request doesn't make sense unless you literally let the app generate images of itself, saving them to a sandboxed folder and creating a GIF file out of them.

Comment: Yes, in runtime with Swift, sure.

Comment: @ElTomato Not sure why the request does not make sense? I need to generate images of view (but for each frame, I can implement gradual animation), save images to the folder (why sandboxes? I can save to documents, upload to internet whatever), and then create GIF (in the question a valid option is just frames as the output).

Comment: You may be able to use ReplayKit to capture the screen and then convert the resulting video into a GIF (transparency would be a problem). But, I doubt you'll have any luck trying to get each frame from SwiftUI